# Alter signature post signing without the private key

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, signature, randomness

There a plethora of signature scheme's but I am wondering if there are scheme's with the following properties:

Given that you know the message, alter the signature with the public key in such a way that a new signature is created (a different hash) but is still valid for the given data.

The reason I am looking for this is that I want a server to sign some random data, but I want to change the signature so the server cannot create a lookup table of the signed values.

Comment: So, I can change, too.

Comment: Are you looking for a blind signature? Or just a rerandomizable signature?

Comment: @Maeher indeed the rerandomizing of the signature.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want the server to do that? If the server has a (message, signature) pair, and it creates a lookup table of those, then these are all valid signatures. So, the fact that a message has many signatures, and these can even be randomized, won't stop the server having valid pairs. Can you elaborate why you want this property? What attack are you trying to prevent?